# Build SQL Query With multiline Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to build query in SQL to get rows the have text like that `'TEXT1\r\nTEXT2'`.

For example something like that:

```
SELECT * 
from Table1 
where Name LIKE '%TEXT1\r\nTEXT2%'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name LIKE '%TEXT1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'TEXT2%';
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can put the characters in with the [`CHAR` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Name LIKE '%TEXT1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'TEXT2%'
```

---

In some RDBMSs you may also be able to put a literal newline in the constant (although it looks like SQL Server ignores this, at least on SQL Fiddle:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Name LIKE '%TEXT1
TEXT2%'
```